# Hamburger menu will not close when LINK is clicked REACT

Tags: reactjs, onclick, tailwind-css

I built a mobile nav hamburger dropdown. The NavMobile links are added to the dropdown in a seperate component. When I try to click on a link in the dropdown it will scroll to the proper section of the page but the mobile dropdown will have to be manually closed which is not what I was hoping for.

Here is the code in the header component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
// import data
import { headerData } from "../data";
//import components
import Nav from "./Nav";
import NavMobile from "./NavMobile";
import Socials from "./Socials";
//import icons
import { TiThMenu } from "react-icons/ti";

const Header = () => {
  //destructure header data
  const { logo } = headerData;
  //header state
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);
  //nav mobile state
  const [navMobile, setNavMobile] = useState(false);
  //scroll event
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
      window.scrollY > 50 ? setIsActive(true) : setIsActive(false);
    });
  });
  return (
    <header
      className={`${
        isActive ? "h-[100px] lg:h-[110px] shadow-lg" : "h-[120px] lg:h-[150px]"
      } fixed bg-white left-0 right-0 z-10 max-w-[1920px] w-full mx-auto transition-all duration-300`}
    >
      <div className="flex justify-between items-center h-full pl-[50px] pr-[60px]">
        {/* logo */}
        <a href="/">
          <img className="w-[188px] h-[90px]" src={logo} alt="Tara Zep Logo" />
        </a>
        {/* nav hidden mobile*/}
        <div className="hidden xl:flex">
          <Nav />
        </div>
        {/* nav menu btn hidden desktop*/}
        <div
          onClick={() => setNavMobile(!navMobile)}
          className="xl:hidden absolute right-[5%] bg-white text-dark p-2 rounded-md cursor-pointer"
        >
          <TiThMenu className="text-3xl" />
        </div>
        {/* nav mobile */}
        <div
          className={`${navMobile ? "max-h-full" : "max-h-0"} ${
            isActive
            ? "top-[100px] lg:top-[110px]"
            : "top-[120px] lg:top-[150px]"
          } fixed bg-white w-full h-full left-0 -z-10 transition-all duration-300`}        
          >
          <NavMobile  onClick={() => setNavMobile(!navMobile)}/> 
        </div>
  {/* social icons hidden show on desktop */}
  <div className="hidden xl:flex">
    <Socials />
  </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

And the NavMobile component:

```
import React from "react";
//import Link
import { Link } from "react-scroll";
//import nav data
import { navData } from "../data";
//import components
import Socials from "./Socials";


const NavMobile = () => {
  //destructure nav data
  const { items } = navData;
  return (
    <nav className="w-full h-full flex flex-col justify-evenly overflow-hidden">
      <ul className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center gap-y-6 py-6 mb-8">
        {items.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <li  key={index}>
              <Link
                to={item.href}
                spy={true}
                smooth={true}
                offset={-70}
                duration={500}
                className="text-2xl font-primary cursor-pointer uppercase"
              >
                {item.name}
              </Link>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
      <div className="text-2xl">
        <Socials />
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};


export default NavMobile;
```

The problem is that when I try to add the
`onClick={() => setNavMobile(!navMobile)}` to the `<NavMobile />` tag it does not work to collapse the dropdown. When i add it to the surrounding div it will work everywhere EXCEPT for on the clicked links. I am using React Scroll for the links.

Answer (score 0):

you may try passing `setNavMobile` funcion to `NavMobile` as a prop and then calling it on `Link` `onClick`